# Phoenix - Client shell Exception while starting the client services(Thin & Thick)

Tags: hadoop, hbase, apache-phoenix

I have facing "NoClassDefFoundError" When execute the phoenix thin client via terminal.
Log Details

```
Exception Details fro thin clients:
[ERROR] Terminal initialization failed; falling back to unsupported java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.phoenix.shaded.org.fusesource.jansi.internal.Kernel32 at org.apache.phoenix.shaded.org.fusesource.jansi.internal.WindowsSupport.getConsoleMode(WindowsSupport.java:50) at org.apache.phoenix.shaded.jline.WindowsTerminal.getConsoleMode(WindowsTerminal.java:177) at org.apache.phoenix.shaded.jline.WindowsTerminal.init(WindowsTerminal.java:80) at org.apache.phoenix.shaded.jline.TerminalFactory.create(TerminalFactory.java:101) at org.apache.phoenix.shaded.jline.TerminalFactory.get(TerminalFactory.java:159) at sqlline.SqlLineOpts.<init>(SqlLineOpts.java:45) at sqlline.SqlLine.<init>(SqlLine.java:55) at sqlline.SqlLine.start(SqlLine.java:397) at sqlline.SqlLine.main(SqlLine.java:291) at org.apache.phoenix.queryserver.client.SqllineWrapper.main(SqllineWrapper.java:93) [ERROR] Terminal initialization failed; falling back to unsupported java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.phoenix.shaded.org.fusesource.jansi.internal.Kernel32 at org.apache.phoenix.shaded.org.fusesource.jansi.internal.WindowsSupport.getConsoleMode(WindowsSupport.java:50) at org.apache.phoenix.shaded.jline.WindowsTerminal.getConsoleMode(WindowsTerminal.java:177) at org.apache.phoenix.shaded.jline.WindowsTerminal.init(WindowsTerminal.java:80) at org.apache.phoenix.shaded.jline.TerminalFactory.create(TerminalFactory.java:101) at sqlline.SqlLine.getConsoleReader(SqlLine.java:723) at sqlline.SqlLine.begin(SqlLine.java:657) at sqlline.SqlLine.start(SqlLine.java:398) at sqlline.SqlLine.main(SqlLine.java:291) at org.apache.phoenix.queryserver.client.SqllineWrapper.main(SqllineWrapper.java:93) Setting property: [incremental, false] Setting property: [isolation, TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED] issuing: !connect jdbc:phoenix:thin:url=http://localhost:8765;serialization=PROTOBUF none none org.apache.phoenix.queryserver.client.Driver Connecting to jdbc:phoenix:thin:url=http://localhost:8765;serialization=PROTOBUF Connected to: Apache Phoenix (version unknown version) Driver: Phoenix Remote JDBC Driver (version unknown version) Autocommit status: true Transaction isolation: TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED Building list of tables and columns for tab-completion (set fastconnect to true to skip)... 92/92 (100%) Done Done sqlline version 1.2.0 0: jdbc:phoenix:thin:url=http://localhost:876>
```

Environment Details

```
OS - windows 7, 8.1 & 10. 
JAVA - jdk 1.7.0_51
Phoenix - 4.11.0-HBase1.2
```

In Linux- No Error Message reproduced.

What should I do to solve this problem.

Comment: is this on WIndows?

Comment: Yes. Windows Cluster.

Comment: maybe do jar tvf *phoenix* jars to check for Kernel32, it sounds like the name / location may have changed and there is a defect in the code